# How do I extract these vocal features using Python?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I'm creating a model to predict, based on several acoustic features, the probability that a person has a certain disease, using this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/parkinsons. These are the features:

MDVP:Fo(Hz) - Average vocal fundamental frequency

MDVP:Fhi(Hz) - Maximum vocal fundamental frequency

MDVP:Flo(Hz) - Minimum vocal fundamental frequency

MDVP:Jitter(%),MDVP:Jitter(Abs),MDVP:RAP,MDVP:PPQ,Jitter:DDP - Several measures of variation in fundamental frequency

MDVP:Shimmer,MDVP:Shimmer(dB),Shimmer:APQ3,Shimmer:APQ5,MDVP:APQ,Shimmer:DDA - Several measures of variation in amplitude

NHR,HNR - Two measures of ratio of noise to tonal components in the voice

RPDE,D2 - Two nonlinear dynamical complexity measures

DFA - Signal fractal scaling exponent

spread1,spread2,PPE - Three nonlinear measures of fundamental frequency variation

Problem is, I have no idea what these mean. I need to be able to extract them from a voice recording. Does anyone have any libraries or resources pertaining to these specific features?

Answer (score 1):

Some (Jitters+Shimmers) of these features you can easily compute with [parselmouth](https://parselmouth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Others are also implemented elsewhere [RPDE](https://pypi.org/project/pyrpde/)